# How to modify .theanorc so that nvcc uses the -m64 flag during compilation?

Tags: windows, theano

I followed the steps at http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#install-windows to install theano but running into problems. One of them is that by default using the `.theanorc` settings on http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#install-windows, on my machine `nvcc` tries to compile theano in 32bit mode as I see following when I try to import theano on python shell (note the `-m32` below):

```
['nvcc', '-shared', '-O3', '--use
/DEBUG', '-D HAVE_ROUND', '-m32',
```

It then runs into problems as it cannot find `cublas.lib` which indeed does not exist on my machine under 32 bit libs stored under `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\lib\Win32` (does this file exist on another users system in the 32bit folder?). I have `cublas.lib` stored under `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\lib\x64` and would therefore like to compile in 64bit mode. To do that I changed `.theanorc` to:

```
[nvcc]
flags = -m64 --use-local-env  --cl-version=2013
```

but this does not give desired effect. `nvcc` is still trying to compile in 32bit mode:

```
['nvcc', '-shared', '-O3', '--use-local-env', '--cl-version=2013', '-Xlinker', '
/DEBUG', '-D HAVE_ROUND', '-m32', '-Xcompiler', '-m64,-DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=a3b91bc
```

Does anyone know the proper syntax how to modify `.theanorc` so that `nvcc` uses the [-m64 flag](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#axzz3WB624BPV) during compilation?

> --machine {32|64} -m   Specify 32-bit vs. 64-bit architecture.
>
> Allowed values for this option: 32, 64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your PYTHON is a 32bit python. We do not support mixing python, g++ and nvcc bit size. THis mean they all must be 32 bit or 64 bit.

Make sure to install all of them as 64 bit.

If you want to try to support this mixed case, check in the theano/sandbox/cuda/nvcc_compiler.py, it is there we do the compilation. Here we add the -m32 flags:

https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/sandbox/cuda/nvcc_compiler.py#L324

If you make this work, a PR with the requested change to Theano would be welcome.

Comment: what is a PR? I am facing a new problem today. I get this message: nvcc fatal   : Value '2013' is not defined for option 'cl-version'. Don't know why I would get this as it used to work earlier without me having to explicitly specify a compiler_bindir. I also executed vcvarsall.bat just in case.

Comment: and when it was working, i was stuck with this error: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
_cublasCreate_v2@4 referenced in function “int __cdecl cublas_init(void)” do you know how to fix this one? why its happening? i am linking with cublas.lib

Comment: fyi i tried this 
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('32bit', 'WindowsPE')
and it seems i indeed have 32bit python. But what does that have to do with compiling 64 bit code? E.g., VS comes as a 32 bit application that gets installed under Program Files (x86) but it compiles source code to 64 bit executable. You don't need a 64bit compiler to produce 64bit machine code.

Comment: Got it. nvcc fatal : Value '2013' is not defined for option 'cl-version' was happening because it was invoking an old version of nvcc.exe (v3.2) when VS 2013 did not exist.

Comment: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cublasCreate_v2@4 referenced in function “int __cdecl cublas_init(void)” was happening because I was linking to an old version of cublas.lib (from v3.2 toolkit) which did not have this method defined.

Comment: since v7 of cuda toolkit doesn't even have a 32bit cublas.lib (at least on windows), it seems its a hard requirement to compile theano in 64bit mode i.e., theano cannot be made to work with -m32 flag using v7 of cuda toolkit. one has to pass -m64 to nvcc compiler.

Comment: on this link http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7_0/Prod/doc/CUDA_Getting_Started_Windows.pdf it says 
Native development using the CUDA Toolkit on x86_32 is unsupported. Deployment
and execution of CUDA applications on x86_32 is still supported, but is limited to use
with GeForce GPUs. To create 32-bit CUDA applications, use the cross-development
capabilities of the CUDA Toolkit on x86_64.
Support for developing and running x86 32-bit applications on x86_64 Windows is
limited to use with:
‣ GeForce GPUs
‣ CUDA Driver
‣ CUDA Runtime (cudart)
‣ CUDA Math Library (math.h)...

Comment: Mixing 32 bit and 64 bit part in one software isn't easy. So the simplest is to install python 64 bit and everything 64 bit. That should work.